# Calculated Value based on a Checkbox field

Tags: infopath

i have a question regarding a tickbox value

if tickbox = yes and set field 1 to =5,000

then commission * field 1 = total

at the moment the total field isn't populating.

what is the best rule or calculation to complete this on an infopath form?

commission is automatically set to 1.75

Answer (score 0):

I would say to do tickbox = Yes then set Field 1 = 5000. Use **Add Rule > **Set a Field's Value**. **If "Is Equal To"** 
then just to be sure
Copy the Field 1 to another Field 2 and then use commission * Filed 2.

You can implement the same using a SharePoint designer WorkFlow too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the calculate column directly.  Add the following formulate to the Total column

```
=IF([Field1],5000*1.79,0)
```

I am putting 0 for the false part of the value, but you can add more condition if needed e.g If false 5000*0.5